# Guardando nomes

Tags: c, ponteiro, estrutura-de-dados, array, char

Eu quero alocar uma string dentro de qualquer estrutura que eu possa buscar estas strings depois. Preciso inserir uma condição para encerrar a inserção de nomes. Eu to pensando em uma estrutura que fique em execução até o termino da leitura, acho que seria um vetor de ponteiros. Estes ponteiros seriam criados no momento em que a string é inserida. Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda, obrigado.

Comment: Seja bem-vindo, Johann. Use as tags para identificar a linguagem de programação que você está usando.

Comment: Linguagem C....

Comment: Basicamente tens 2 hipoteses: o vetor de ponteiros ou uma "linked list".

Comment: E como seria estas linked lists?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma estrutura de lista para adicionar quantos nomes quiser.

```
typedef struct __list__{
    const char *name;
    struct __list__ *next;
}list; // Estrutura de linked list

void list_insert(list **l, const char *name){
    // Cria uma nova posição na lista
    list *_new = (list*) malloc(sizeof(list));
    _new->name = name;
    _new->next = NULL;

    if(!*l){ // Se a lista estiver vazia, Insere o primeiro item
        *l = _new;
        return;
    }

    list *buff = *l;
    while(buff->next)
        buff = buff->next; // Anda até o final da lista

    buff->next = _new; // inseri um novo item no final da lista
}
```

com essa estrutura, você vai conseguir inserir quantos nomes quiser em C.